# Oxyplot to interrupt DateTimeAxis serie

Tags: c#, oxyplot

How can I interrupt serie at certain point, then continue from later point?
For example I have date time axis as Y, then the data exist until certain date, then there is no data and later again I have data. What I want is NOT interpolate last data point where data has been interrupted with continuation, but I want to stop the plot and continue once data still there.

[image]

In the screenshot above the linear slope is due to missing data. What I want is to avoid that line. Still I want all that interrupted data to be within the same serie.

Update:

```
foreach (var dp in readings)
{
    data.Add(new DateValue {
        Date = dp.Date,
        Temperature = dp.Data.Where(y => y.Cell == c.Number).
                              Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.GetType().GetProperty(sensor.PropertyName).GetValue(x, null))).
                              FirstOrDefault() });

    if (lastDate != null && (dp.Date - lastDate).TotalMinutes > 10)
    {
        data.Add(new DateValue
        {
            Date = dp.Date,
            Temperature = double.NaN
        });
        Console.WriteLine("break");
    }

    lastDate = dp.Date;
}
mode1Data.Add(c.Number, data);
```

Comment: What counts as data doesn't exist? Meaning if you have a datetime 12/12/2012 10:00:00, and the next value is 12/12/2012 10:30:00, then data doesn't exist between those two times, but I am assuming that's not what you mean. In other words, how long between two points counts as data doesn't exist?

Comment: Data is being sampled each 5 minutes. If the gap is more that, then it is considered as interruption

Comment: Are you using a lineseries?

Comment: Yes sir, `LineSeries` is what I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `DataPoint.Undefined`, creates a break in the line. You could also style the "broken line" (code example taken from oxyplot LineSeriesExample.cs):

### Without data binding:

```
 var model = new PlotModel("Broken line");

 var s1 = new LineSeries
     {
         // If you want to style
         //BrokenLineColor = OxyColors.Gray,
         //BrokenLineThickness = 1,
         //BrokenLineStyle = LineStyle.Dash
         BrokenLineStyle = LineStyle.None
     };

 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 26));
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 30));
 s1.Points.Add(DataPoint.Undefined);
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 25));
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 26));
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(25, 36));
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(30, 40));
 s1.Points.Add(DataPoint.Undefined);
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(30, 20));
 s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 10));
 model.Series.Add(s1);
```

[image]

### With data binding:

xaml:

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="plot1" Title="Binding ItemsSource" Subtitle="{Binding Subtitle}">
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries Title="Maximum" DataFieldX="Time" DataFieldY="Maximum" Color="Red" LineStyle="Solid" StrokeThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Measurements}"/>
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Model:

```
Measurements = new Collection<Measurement>();
int N = 500;
Subtitle = "N = " + N;

var r = new Random(385);
double dy = 0;
double y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    dy += r.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
    y += dy;

    // Create a line break
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        Measurements.Add(new Measurement
        {
            Time = double.NaN, // For DateTime put DateTime.MinValue
            Value = double.NaN
        });   
    }
    else
    {
        Measurements.Add(new Measurement
        {
            Time = 2.5 * i / (N - 1),
            Value = y / (N - 1),
        });   
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but how can I have this if I am not using `DataPoint` class? Instead in series I am using my own objects, specified in ItemSource, then `DataFieldX` and `DataFieldY`.

Comment: I haven't tried, but DataPoint.Undefined has double.NaN as x, y. Trying setting DataFieldX and DataFieldY to double.NaN.

Comment: The problem is I can't add double.NaN for date time axis. I've tried just to add value as NaN, which didn't work.

Comment: `Time = double.NaN` is what I can't do, because I have `DateTime` variable... I've also updated my question with some code.

Comment: try setting it to DateTime.MinValue